# How to fix Undefined offset and Could not find validation handler for name

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

My Validation code is like this:

```
public $validate = array(

    'name' => array(
        'rule' =>array(
            'rule'=>'notEmpty',
            'required' => true ,
            'allowEmpty' => false ,
            'on'=>'create',
            'message' => 'This field cannot be left empty'
        )
    ),
    'email' => array(
        'rule1' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'required' => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'on'=>'create',
            'message' => 'This email has already been taken.'
         ),
        'rule2' => array(
            'rule' => array('email'),
            'required' => true,
            'on'=>'create',
            'message' => 'Please supply a valid email address.'
        ),
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'Not Empty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'Password must not be empty.'
        ),
        'password_contains' => array(
            'rule'=>'alphaNumeric',
            'message' => 'Password must contain letters and numbers'
        ),
        'password_length' => array(
            'rule' => array('lengthBetween', 5, 15),
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'Passwords must be between 5 and 15 characters long.'
        ),
        'passwords match' => array(
            'rule' => 'matchPasswords',
            'message' => 'Your passwords do not match'
        )
    ),
    'password_again' => array(
        'Not Empty' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty',
            'required' => true,
            'message' => 'Password must not be empty.'
        ),

    )
);

public function matchPasswords($data)
{
    if ($data['password'] == $this->data['User']['password_again']) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->invalidate('password_again', 'Your passwords do not match');
        return false;
    }
}
```

But everytime i am running the code i am getting these errors:

> Notice (8): Undefined offset: 0 [CORE\Cake\Model\Validator\CakeValidationRule.php, line 342]
>   Warning (512): Could not find validation handler for name [CORE\Cake\Model\Validator\CakeValidationRule.php, line 281]

I am not getting what is the problem.
Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here

```
'name' => array(
    'rule' => array(
        'rule'=> 'notEmpty',
        //...
    )
)
```

Just change that first `rule` key to something else

```
'name' => array(
    'validName' => array(
        'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
        //...
    )
)
```

The reason for these errors is as follows. When `rule` key is found, Cake tries to parse the name of the validation handler from its value. In second example, it tries to get value at *index 0* from `array('notEmpty')`, which is resolved to `notEmpty` method, everything's fine.
Returning back to your original `name` rule, Cake tries to get value at *index 0* from `array('rule'=>'notEmpty',...)`, there is no such index(offset), validation handler cannot be found and the error is triggered.